# How to restore realm file when sandbox changes?

Tags: ios, database, path, realm, sandbox

I use this directory to save my realm db.
`[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];`

When sandbox path changes, everything is ok, my bd relocates into the new directory.

But before that, I was using this directory.
`[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]`
This is an absolute URL, so every time I was losing my db info.

Now I want to connect this 2 version, now, after app update users get empty db.

So is there way to get previous sandbox url to restore realm db with correct path?

Comment: In what case does the sandbox path change? Why are you using something other than the default Realm path?

Comment: This is my path.
`file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9149AB65-F96D-4973-B809-1E21472B51B1/data/Containers/Data/Application/4B988C1B-1E04-46DF-9739-0B653202CAF4/Documents/`

This part `4B988C1B-1E04-46DF-9739-0B653202CAF4` changes when I am creating app build with another computer.
So I need to relocate my bd files to the new directory, otherwise, they are empty

Comment: So you are not moving data in your sandbox, you are actually running the app on a totally different user account. As I mentioned previously, if you simply use the default realm location, the app will always find it. That path looks like the default at first glance so it won't make any difference that what the enclosing folder is - Realm default will always be where Realm can find it. Is there some reason you are not doing that?